# Nested abstract class in an abstract class and how to implement it

Tags: c#, abstract-class, inner-classes, abstraction

I have an abstract class A and a abstract method  with a parameter which is again abstract class B defined in the same abstract class A. When I extended this abstract class A as apart of another class C how can I implement the method with parameter of nested abstract class.

```
public abstract class A<T, V>
{
    public abstract int GetObject(T t, V v);
    public abstract int GetAnotherObject(B b);
    public abstract class B{}
}
```

This class is extended by another class C

```
public class C: A<ABC, DEF>
{
        public C()
        {

        }
        public override int GetObject(ABC abc, DEF def)
        {
            return 10;
        }

        public override int GetAnotherObject(B b)
        {
            return 15;
        }
}
```

How to implement class B with some properties and pass in GetAnotherObject method. Could someone please help me.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ECMA:

> Any class nested inside a generic
>   class declaration or a generic struct
>   declaration (§25.2) is itself a
>   generic class declaration, since type
>   parameters for the containing type
>   shall be supplied to create a
>   constructed type.

So, you cannot implement nested `B` without providing type arguments for `A`.

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new C();
    var result = c.GetAnotherObject(new BImpl<string, int>());
}

public class BImpl<T, V> : A<T, V>.B
{
    public override int BM()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

// Or you can supply type arguments right here
//public class BImpl : A<string, int>.B
//{
//  public override int BM()
//  {
//      return 1;
//  }
//}

public abstract class A<T, V>
{
    public abstract int GetObject(T t, V v);
    public abstract int GetAnotherObject(B b);
    public abstract class B
    {
        public abstract int BM();
    }
}

public class C : A<string, int>
{
    public C()
    {

    }

    public override int GetObject(string abc, int def)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public override int GetAnotherObject(B b)
    {
        return b.BM();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is throwing an error saying Class doesn't implement inherited  abstract member as Class B never defined in C and I want to know how to overcome this.

Comment: I got one more doubt what if there are some new properties defined in BImpl and I would like to access them in GetAnotherObject()?

Comment: @KDKR, you cannot unless you provide BImpl type into the GetAnotherObject or you can just cast, but then why would you even use the B abstraction.

Comment: The basic reason why I abstracted B is to pass variable number of parameters to method GetAnotherObject based on the requirement in different scenarios.

Comment: I don't think I understand you. How are you going to variate the number of parameters by programming to abstract B? In general your code looks a bit overcomplicated for me, I don't think you actually have a problem that requires such complicated solution, but I don't know about the problem you're trying to solve. Maybe you should try to formulate what are you trying to achieve, create a new question and ask for a design solution, not a technical one.

Comment: Sure @aush I will post a new question. Thanks though for answering my questions.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close already.

```
public class C<ABC, DEF> : A<ABC, DEF>
{
    public C()
    {

    }
    public override int GetObject(ABC abc, DEF def)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    // since B is a nested class of A, it has no scope outside of A
    // outside of the definition of A, it must always be referred to as A.B
    public override int GetAnotherObject(A<ABC,DEF>.B b)
    {
        return 15;
    }
}

public class D : A<ABC,DEF>.B
{
    // implementation of A.B
}
```

Keep in mind that `C` will *always* take exactly `A.B`.  You will never be able to define an implementation of `A.B` (let's call it `D`) and have `C`'s method signature refer to that in the override.  `GetAnotherObject` is defined in A as taking an `A.B` and must therefore be implemented to accept *any* `A.B`, not some specific implementation of `A.B`.

RE: your comment on how to implement `A.B` inside `C`

There is no point to implementing `A.B` inside `C`.  `C` will still have to have `A.B` in its method signature.  But if you really must, for some reason.

```
public class C<ABC, DEF> : A<ABC, DEF> 
{
    // C's implementation of A

    public override int GetAnotherObject(A<ABC,DEF>.B b)
    {
        return 15;
    }

    public class D : A<ABC,DEF>.B
    {
        // implementation of A.B
    }
}
```

Note that `GetAnotherObject` still takes an `A.B`, not a `D`.

Comment: I agree with what you said but the issue here is It is throwing an error saying Class C didn't implement the inherited abstract member. My primary goal is to define B with some properties before passing it in GetAnotherObject.

Comment: As @aush pointed out, A must always be declared with type parameters.  So B must always be defined as `A<ABC,DEF>.B`, which I oversimplified in my examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class C<ABC, DEF> : A<ABC, DEF>
{
    public C()
    {

    }
    public override int GetObject(ABC abc, DEF def)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public override int GetAnotherObject(B b)
    {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

Just postfix the class with the generics.

Comment: my concern here is I am getting an error while implementing abstract member class B with some properties and  passing it in GetAnotherObject method. I would like to know how exactly to implement abstract class B in class C and pass it as parameter in GetAnotherObject.